# Возможно ли как-то упростить запись

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
           <CreateButton
            disabled={
              data.name.length < 5 ||
              data.name.length > 100 ||
              data.description.length < 10 ||
              data.description.length > 100
            }
            onClick={onHandleSave}
          >
            Save
          </CreateButton>
```

Comment: Можно попробовать применить деструктуризацию. Тогда не придется тянуть ключи.

Comment: Можно еще функции создать на name и на description и в нужном месте вызывать, но скорее всего это излишинство.

Comment: Да, да, описать функцию outOfRange() и готово! Тогда `disabled={outOfRange(data.name.length, 5, 100) || outOfRange(data.description.length, 10, 100)}`.

Comment: А еще лучше - валидировать каждый инпут отдельно, а кнопку выключать если вся форма не валидна